# How to create Excel spreadsheet from HTML Table using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, phpexcel

I've made table on View ,now i want to report it to Excel (PHPExcel) using CodeIgniter,im trying to find a simple reporting system,here's my script on controller so far :

```
  function excel(){
    $data['bf']=$this->report->branch();


    $tahun = $this->input->post('tahun');
    $branch= $this->input->post('branch');

    /*$data['data'] = $this->report->getdata($tahun);
    $data['data2'] = $this->report->getdata($tahun);
     // $data['bfb'] = $this->report->getdata($tahun,$branch); */
    $data['show'] = $this->report->show();

    $data['bal'] = $this->report->getbal($tahun);
    $data['bdg'] = $this->report->getbdg($tahun);
      $data['bgr'] = $this->report->getbgr($tahun);
      $data['bjm'] = $this->report->getbjm($tahun);
      $data['bkp'] = $this->report->getbkp($tahun);
      $data['bks'] = $this->report->getbks($tahun);
      $data['bnk'] = $this->report->getbnk($tahun);
      $data['crb'] = $this->report->getcrb($tahun);
      $data['jkt'] = $this->report->getjkt($tahun);
      $data['jktm'] = $this->report->getjktm($tahun);
      $data['jmb'] = $this->report->getjmb($tahun);
      $data['knd'] = $this->report->getknd($tahun);
      $data['lpg'] = $this->report->getlpg($tahun);
      $data['mad'] = $this->report->getmad($tahun);
       $data['mdn'] = $this->report->getmdn($tahun);
      $data['mks'] = $this->report->getmks($tahun);
      $data['mlg'] = $this->report->getmlg($tahun);
        $data['pkb'] = $this->report->getpkb($tahun);
      $data['plb'] = $this->report->getplb($tahun);
      $data['pnt'] = $this->report->getpnt($tahun);


  $html = $this->load->view('report/report', $data, true);


$tmpfile = time().'.html';
file_put_contents($tmpfile, $html);


$reader = new PHPExcel_Reader_HTML; 
$content = $reader->load($tmpfile); 

// Pass to writer and output as needed
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($content, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('excelfile.xls');


unlink($tmpfile);

    }
```

when i use that script,,i can't download it, pls correct my script , Thanks

Comment: You're saving the file to `excelfile.xls` on the web server.... are you then using `readfile()` or similar to try and download?

Comment: Why don't you simply set the appropriate headers, and then save to `php://output`

Comment: can you give me example using headers pls ??

Comment: pls correct my script,,,i need your help ...when i press the button to download,,nothing happens,,

Comment: There's plenty of examples showing this in the `/Examples` folder of PHPExcel

Comment: mm,,ok i will try that

Comment: im just need your correction,,why i can't download my excel ..

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my demo project i did excel export in Codeigniter 
https://github.com/eboominathan/Basic-CRUD-in-Codeigniter

Comment: what the password of admin ??

Answer (score 0):

like this ??

```
function excel(){

   $CI->load->library('Excel'); 
    $data['bf']=$this->report->branch();


    $tahun = $this->input->post('tahun');
    $branch= $this->input->post('branch');

    /*$data['data'] = $this->report->getdata($tahun);
    $data['data2'] = $this->report->getdata($tahun);
     // $data['bfb'] = $this->report->getdata($tahun,$branch); */
    $data['show'] = $this->report->show();

    $data['bal'] = $this->report->getbal($tahun);
    $data['bdg'] = $this->report->getbdg($tahun);
      $data['bgr'] = $this->report->getbgr($tahun);
      $data['bjm'] = $this->report->getbjm($tahun);
      $data['bkp'] = $this->report->getbkp($tahun);
      $data['bks'] = $this->report->getbks($tahun);
      $data['bnk'] = $this->report->getbnk($tahun);
      $data['crb'] = $this->report->getcrb($tahun);
      $data['jkt'] = $this->report->getjkt($tahun);
      $data['jktm'] = $this->report->getjktm($tahun);
      $data['jmb'] = $this->report->getjmb($tahun);
      $data['knd'] = $this->report->getknd($tahun);
      $data['lpg'] = $this->report->getlpg($tahun);
      $data['mad'] = $this->report->getmad($tahun);
       $data['mdn'] = $this->report->getmdn($tahun);
      $data['mks'] = $this->report->getmks($tahun);
      $data['mlg'] = $this->report->getmlg($tahun);
        $data['pkb'] = $this->report->getpkb($tahun);
      $data['plb'] = $this->report->getplb($tahun);
      $data['pnt'] = $this->report->getpnt($tahun);


  $html = $this->load->view('report/report', $data, true);
  $filename = 'Report Data Actual vs Target Branch '.date('Y-m-d').'.xls';                        //save our workbook as this file name
   header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); //mime type
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $filename . '"'); //tell browser what's the file name
   header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache
   //save it to Excel5 format (excel 2003 .XLS file), change this to 'Excel2007' (and adjust the filename extension, also the header mime type)
   //if you want to save it as .XLSX Excel 2007 format
   $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($CI->excel, 'Excel5');
   //force user to download the Excel file without writing it to server's HD
   $objWriter->save('php://output');
```